# Using MSHTML how do you set the focus on an input field?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mshtml

Using MSHTML I'd like to set the user focus on a text element, what I've been given and tried so far doesn't work.

```
CComPtr<IHTMLInputTextElement> field;
field->put_value( .. );  // I have the right element as I can set the text...

VARIANT vStatus;
vStatus.vt = VT_BOOL;
vStatus.boolVal = VARIANT_TRUE;
field->put_status(vStatus);

CComQIPtr<IHTMLInputElement> inputElement(field);
if( inputElement )
  inputElement->put_status(VARIANT_TRUE);
```

and by doesn't work I mean it runs and reports no errors but the focus on the web page doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CComQIPtr<IHTMLElement2 > element2(field);
if(element2!=NULL) element2->focus();
```

Comment: Thanks, sometimes finding the right interface for the action you want is half the challenge.